# If a human own the planet, by proprety law, what can he do?

Tags: humans, earth, law, property

Let me explain myself

the term "Owning the planet" refer to the possession, the control a person intentionally exercises toward a thing, here, the planet and what it's composed of.
The concept of "control" isn't meant here to be apply on livings. Only on the thing. No dictator's concept.

So let say i own the planet, can i say to a country attacking a other country via fighter jet: stop flying in my sky ?
or
Your satellites are in my atmosphere, you own free wifi to all humans ?
or
You took the gold you trying to sell from my land, you can't sell it for fiat money

Comment: Welcome to the site, Tag. Can you clarify what "own the planet" means in context i.e. do you control all world governments and militaries? The answer is entirely dependent on whether you're an authoritarian dictator or the elected president of the New United Nations. I suspect the real answer, though, is "whatever suits the plot."

Comment: You can *say* just about anything you like. Unless you have a way to *enforce* your ownership of the planet, the inhabitants will consider you just another nutter.

Comment: Read Cordwainer Smith's novel *Norstrillia*. It is about a boy who buys the planet Earth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norstrilia

Answer (score 7):

**Ownership requires a framework of laws, agreed by all parties**

The term 'ownership' indicates a general accepted agreement that people (which also need to be defined) has some form of rights (which need to be defined) over items, objects and land (again, all of which need to be defined).

The key though is *agreement*: without consensus you would not be able form an idea of what ownership means.

So in other words, all the scenarios in your question '*could*' be ok, but **only if there is broad consensus** that they are the case.

Further to this, it helps if such agreements are defined precisely in writing, such as in legislation or law, to enable it's enforcement, or for settling of disputes if an ownership dispute arises (which given your scenarios, could happen quite a lot).